# Add CSS cursor property when using "pointer-events: none"

Tags: css

I'm trying to disable a specific link and apply cursor style but this CSS command `cursor: text;` won't effect. The cursor is always default. I'm using latest Firefox version.

CSS:

```
pointer-events: none !important;
cursor: text;
color: Blue;
```

Comment: @PHPglue Two things: http://www.w3fools.com and it really doesn't work, even when it's just this element in the page: http://jsfiddle.net/brh9r8h6/

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Using `pointer-events: none` will [disable all mouse interactions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) with that element. If you wanted to change the `cursor` property, you would have to apply the changes to the parent element. You could wrap the link with an element and add the `cursor` property to it.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/unorggoj/)

**HTML**

```
<span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">Some Link</a>
</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    cursor: text;  /* This is used */
}
.wrapper a {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

There are a few browser inconsistencies, though. To make this work in IE11, it seems like you need a pseudo element. The pseudo element also allows you to select the text in FF. Oddly enough, you can select the text in Chrome without it.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wu0LunL/)

```
.wrapper:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: your code works unless i delete its parent tags, but it is in <div><li><span> and in this case it is still default cursor

Comment: @user3721912 Do you mind providing an example? That would be helpful.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want to say, i mean my span tag stays not alone it has <div><li> parents,it is encircled with <div><li> tags

Answer (score 65):

It's pretty long since original question, but this is my solution without any wrapping element and cursor with no pointer-events:

```
<!-- Add tabindex="-1" so that element cannot be reached by keyboard -->
<a href="url" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" onfocus="blur()">Disabled link</a>
```

CSS:

```
/* Adding cursor just works: */
a[aria-disabled="true"] {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

/* Makes link non-clickable: */
a[aria-disabled="true"]:active {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[**CodePen Example**](https://codepen.io/petr001/pen/xxGYdWy)

**EDIT:**

- Chrome has started to add focus on click on elements with tabindex attribute (even with tabindex="-1"). Fastest solution is to set `onfocus="blur()"` to unfocus element.
- You need to prevent focusing the element otherwise it could be activated by enter key

**EDIT 2**

- Replaced `class="disabled"` with `aria-disabled="true"` to meet the a11y ;)

Comment: This should be the selected answer! Shows cursor icon and allows for pointer-events none, great solution.

Comment: Great! I used your answer to achieve the same by adding a style `a.disable-link { cursor: not-allowed; }`  and then only disabling pointer events when active 
`a.disable-link:active { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Very clever, but it doesn't work for all possible circumstances. Still, a wonderful idea.

Comment: Hey Slbox, interesting. What are the circumstances when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 13):

By specifying `pointer-events:none` you are actively declaring that there is no mouse interaction between the element and the cursor. Therefore it cannot have a cursor either - it's invisible to **all** mouse behaviours.

[Proof to be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/z4sL9m7k/).

Comment: again, poor logic to justify this. Let's say you do want mouse interaction, but you are implementing this yourself in JavaScript. Or, you are not using JavaScript, but want to style something like the textarea resize, adding the <-> cursor to the bottom right, but you don't want that to block the underlying resize functionality, so you make pointer-events: none;, but that removes the cursor. Abysmal logic.

I can't see how this is an answer to the question.

Comment: This answer seems to be incorrect as a cursor still changes it's style to the default element cursor style when the mouse is moved over it when the <code>pointer-events:none</code> style is set on it.  e.g. An anchor element in chrome will detect the cursor over it and change to a hand by default (The mouse interacted with the element).

Answer (score 4):

Remove `pointer-events: none !important;`. Disable the link using JavaScript:

```
anchorElement.onclick = function(){
  return false;
}
```

If you don't know JavaScript `anchorElement` is the Node or Element itself. The most common way to get an Element is by using the HTML `id` attribute. Let's say we have:

```
<a id='whatever' href='#'>Text Here</a>
```

You code could be:

```
document.getElementById('whatever').onclick = function(){
  return false;
}
```

There are a number other ways to get Nodes.

Comment: it seems logical but i'm poor at JavaScript. It would be nice if you show a sample usage

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the links unactive, and with a custom cursor, do that:

```css
.loading { cursor:wait; }
.loading * { pointer-events:none; }
```

```html
<span class="loading">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

My use case was a draggable element that couldn't have any pointer-event nor any parent element with a pointer-event.

I solved it by conditionally applying a global style forcing a grabbing cursor only while dragging. (I'm using React and styled-components, but the same logic can be applied on vanilla js).

```
const SetDraggingCursor = createGlobalStyle`
  * {
    cursor: grabbing !important;
  }
`;

// ...

{isDragging && <SetDraggingCursor />}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create another div and position it exactly on your last div and make a css like these :

```
.example{
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); //opacity:0
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than wrapper, this can be done with pure CSS from the insides as well. (I use this with material web component, so the code gets a little more complex.)

```
button:disabled {
    > * {
        cursor: not-allowed;
        pointer-events: initial;
    }

    &::before {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }

    &::after {
        background-color: #fff0;
    }
}
```

```html
<button>
    <svg .../>
</button>
```

I also tried `::before` and `::after` with `button:disabled` directly, but just couldn't make it happen...