# How do I make it were the outside of my png image cannot be clicked and only the actual "image" part can be clicked?

Tags: javascript

Please help I have struggled on this with my cookie clicker-like game and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Elaborate more on your problem please. snippet/visual etc...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 'event delegation' would be useful
Assuming your image includes some distinguishing factor (className or id);
Basically add an event listener to the whole container/window
and observe if className matches with your image else do nothing

```
const imageClickObserver = (e) => {
  if(e.target.className === 'image') {
   cookiePoints++;
   alert('clicked on image')
 }else {
   return;
 }
}

window.addEventListener('click' imageClickObserver)
```

If I misunderstood your question and all you care of is to make your elements 'clickable'/'not clickable' then you can read this thread.
[Add CSS cursor property when using "pointer-events: none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654413/add-css-cursor-property-when-using-pointer-events-none)